# Java SonarQube rule squid:S1948 - how to use serializable lists without being bound to e.g. ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, sonarqube

The SonarQube rule [squid:S1948](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1948) requires that all fields of a serializable class are either serializable or transient. [Another rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1319) states to rather use the interface than the implementation types.

When I have a

```
public class myClass implements Serializable
{
  List<String> names;
  ...
}
```

then `names` should rather be a `List<String>` than e.g. `ArrayList<String>`. But then rule S1948 tells us that `List` isn't serializable.

Solution at a first glance: define an `interface SerializableList` - maybe like this:

```
public interface SerializableList<E> extends List<E>, Serializable
{
}
```

If we declare `names` to be a

```
  SerializableList<String> names;
```

the warning from rule S1948 is gone, but an assignment `names = new ArrayList<String>();` results in a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to SerializableList<String>`.

Two questions:

- why can I declare `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();` without a warning nor need to cast, but cannot declare `SerializableList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();`? I wonder, because `ArrayList<E> implements List<E>, Serializable, ...` - why isn't it a `SerializableList`?
- how to declare `names` in a way that neither S1948 nor the other rule will give a warning, but I can still be free to use any kind of `List` that is also `Serializable` (like `ArrayList`, ...) and without need for an explicit cast.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is the version of SonarJava that is installed on your sonarqube Server ?

Comment: @benzonico 4.14, why do you ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why can I declare `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();` without a warning nor need to cast, but cannot declare `SerializableList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();`? I wonder, because `ArrayList<E> implements List<E>, Serializable, ...` - why isn't it a `SerializableList`?

You want to use a structure/feature which does not exist in Java ("a grouping interface"). Right now you introduced a new type `SerializableList` which extends other types:

```
List    Serializable
  ↑          ↑
SerializableList
```

`ArrayList` also extends both parent types of the `SerializableList`:

```
List   Serializable
  ↑         ↑
   ArrayList
```

but they are no connection between `SerializableList` and `ArrayList`. If we define a new type:

```
public class SerializableListImpl extends ArrayList implements SerializableList
```

then we have:

```
   --------→ List ←---------
   |                       |
   |  --→ Serializable ←-- |
   | |                   | |
ArrayList          SerializableList
      ↑                 ↑
      SerializableListImpl
```

and finally:

```
List serializableList = new SerializableListImpl();
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof List); // true
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof Serializable); // true
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof ArrayList); // true
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof SerializableList); // true

List arrayList = new ArrayList();
System.out.println(arrayList instanceof List); // true
System.out.println(arrayList instanceof Serializable); // true
System.out.println(arrayList instanceof ArrayList); // true
System.out.println(arrayList instanceof SerializableList); // false ← not in the hierarchy
```

> how to declare names in a way that neither S1948 nor the other rule will give a warning, but I can still be free to use any kind of `List` that is also `Serializable` (like `ArrayList`, ...) and without need for an explicit cast.

You cannot. Not every implementation of the `List` interface have to be also `Serializable`. Anyone can define a new type:

```
public class MyList implements List {
    ...
}
```

assign to the `names` field and then:

```
List myList = new MyList();
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof List); // true
System.out.println(serializableList instanceof Serializable); // false ← not in the hierarchy
```

As I wrote at the top such feature as "a grouping interface":

```
SerializableList == List<String>&&Serializable
```

does not exist so you have to mark the issue as `Won't Fix`.